# PHP "if" statement looking for between two numbers

Tags: php, if-statement

I need help on a if statement here is what is going on.

I have a value being pulled $paint['product_id']

I need to say if that value is between
81501 - 81599 or
81701 - 81799 
say blah

else if that value is between 
81001 - 81099 or
81301 - 81399
say blah2

else if
86501 - 86599 or
86001 - 86099 or
85001 - 85099
say blah3

and say nothing if it does not apply.

What id did try

```
<? if ($paint['product_id'] >= 81501 && $x <= 81599 || $paint['product_id'] >= 81701 && $x <= 81799):?>
blah
<? elseif ($paint['product_id'] >= 81001 && $x <= 81099 || $paint['product_id'] >= 81301 && $x <= 81399):?>
blah2
<? elseif ($paint['product_id'] >= 86501 && $x <= 86599 || $paint['product_id'] >= 86001 && $x <= 86099 || $paint['product_id'] >= 85001 && $x <= 85099):?>
blah3
<? endif;?>
```

The problem I am having is "blah" is showing up on items in the blah3 category.

Hope that makes sense and thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where did `$x` come from??

Comment: Are these ranges the real values?

Comment: I just pulled examples I found online to try them out $x means nothing and yes these are the real ranges I need.

Comment: Based on the accepted answer, this is an Off-topic: Typo question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `$x` with `$paint['product_id']`.

Comment: That seemed to do it, the code I had was working just not 100% correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You should group them with brackets:

```
if( ($x > 10 && $x < 20) || ($x > 40 && $x < 50) ) { ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating a user defined function, e.g.

```
function between($x, $lim1, $lim2) {
  if ($lim1 < $lim2) {
    $lower = $lim1; $upper = $lim2;
  }
  else {
    $lower = $lim2; $upper = $lim1;
  }
  return (($x >= $lower) && ($x <= $upper));
}
```

Then the rest of your code becomes much more legible:

```
if between($paint['product_id'], 81501, 81599) blah;
```

As given, the "between" function will work even if you don't know ahead of time whether the first or the second argument is larger.

Answer (score 1):

You need more parenthesis

```
<?php
<? if (($paint['product_id'] >= 81501 && $x <= 81599) || ($paint['product_id'] >= 81701 && $x <= 81799)):?>
blah
<? elseif (($paint['product_id'] >= 81001 && $x <= 81099) || ($paint['product_id'] >= 81301 && $x <= 81399)):?>
blah2
<? elseif (($paint['product_id'] >= 86501 && $x <= 86599) || ($paint['product_id'] >= 86001 && $x <= 86099) || ($paint['product_id'] >= 85001 && $x <= 85099)):?>
blah3
<? endif;?>
```

Comment: If you're going to point that out you might want to make sure you put them all in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

there are at least 3 ways to solve it.

First solution has been already posted by users

Second solution is to create between function and use it.

```
function between($number, $from, $to)
{
   return $number>$from && $number<$to;
}

  if(between($paint['product_id'], 81501, 81599) || $paint['product_id'], 81701, 81799))
   echo 'blah'; 
  else if(between($paint['product_id'], 81001, 81099) || $paint['product_id'], 81301, 81399))
   echo 'blah2';

  else if(between($paint['product_id'], 86501, 86599) || $paint['product_id'], 86001, 86099) || $paint['product_id'], 85001, 85099))
   echo 'blah3';
  else echo 'it does not apply';
```

Third solution is to use `range()` function and `in_array()` function

example `if(in_array($paint['product_id'], range(81501, 81599)))`

rest goes the same

Comment: At about the same time that you wrote your answer, and without seeing it, I created a similar `between` function... Note that OP was using `>=` - range includes end points.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($paint['product_id'] >= 81501 && $x <= 81599 || $paint['product_id'] >= 81701         && $x <= 81799){
    echo "blah";
}
elseif ($paint['product_id'] >= 81001 && $x <= 81099 || $paint['product_id'] >= 81301 && $x <= 81399){
    echo "blah2";
}
elseif ($paint['product_id'] >= 86501 && $x <= 86599 || $paint['product_id'] >= 86001 && $x <= 86099 || $paint['product_id'] >= 85001 && $x <= 85099){
    echo "blah2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hellow i'm going to desribe how to use if condition between two numbers in PHP in easy steps.

```
<?php

$a= 65;
$b= 9;

if($a<$b)
    {
        echo  "$a this is correct";
    }

else{
    echo "$b this is greater than $a";
}


?>
```